# How to use a Python class file in another script (in Matlab)

Tags: python, matlab, class, rdkit

I am new to python and mainly use Matlab. I found some Python code on Github (https://github.com/simonmb/fragmentation_algorithm) that I want to run in Matlab, but I can't even manage to write a function in Python to run the code with any input. When I try to run the function I wrote (called 'RunFrag.py') in the Console in PyCharm, I only get the following error: NameError: name 'RunFrag' is not defined, even though the script is in the same folder. The file from Github ('fragmenter.py') defines a class and has the line `__name__ == '__main__'` and I have no idea how to deal with this, in Matlab classes occur rather rarely.

Can anyone help me with creating a function where I can just enter a SMILES molecule as input and get the fragmentation out?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the Code from the RunFrag function I wrote (the additionally needed fragmenter.py file can be found at the github link):

```
def RunFrag(smiles):
    from .fragmenter import fragmenter
    
    fragmentation_scheme = {
        'CH2' : '[CH2]',
        'OH' : '[OH]',
        'CH3' : '[CH3]',
        'CH2-CH2' : '[CH2][CH2]'
    }
    
    fragmentation_scheme_order1 = ['CH2-CH2', 'CH3', 'CH2', 'OH']
    
    frg = fragmenter(fragmentation_scheme, fragmentation_scheme_order=fragmentation_scheme_order1, algorithm='simple')
    fragmentation, success, fragmentation_matches = frg.fragment(smiles)
        return smiles, fragmentation, success
```

Comment: In a CLI, can you run the module? `python fragmenter.py` in the folder where the code lives?

Comment: The answer is right there in the source code on git after the line you referred to.

Comment: @Dschoni This is the error I get with python fragmenter.py
File "<input>", line 1
    python fragmenter.py
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Inside pycharm, just import the module `import fragmenter.py` and call one of the samples in the source. My code snippet was meant for CLI (cmd, bash...). If you need more help, feel free to write an email to the mail linked on my SO profile.

Comment: Import should be on the top level not inside the function. Other than that, this looks quite good. Do you get any error?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. So I used the following in the console:
import fragmenter.py
smiles, fragmentation, success = RunFrag('CCCCC=C')

And then I got an error, that rdkit cannot be found in fragmenter.py, even though in the Run/Debug Config I used an environment with rdkit (my-rdkit-env)

Comment: That's correct, smiles shouldn't be in fragmenter.py. Can you double-check rdkit being in the used env by issueing `import rdkit` directly? Again: Happy to help via e-mail but SO is not meant for extended discussion.